# Reducing the number of queries to the DB when using neo4j gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, cypher

Using the neo4j gem, and returning a single object, it performs a query for every relation.  Some of these relations also have relations, and it becomes a huge burden on the DB and slows performance.

I have used .with_associations() but, this seems to only work when using .each, not when you just want a single item.

`Company.where(id: :company_id]).with_associations(:company_location)` or 
`Company.where(id: :company_id])`

When serializing the above query, both will make at least two calls to the database.

Any ideas or tricks to help reduce the load on the DB?

Thanks

Comment: How about eager loading use `includes` ?

Comment: The neo4j gem does not have that method built-in. https://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/9.2.x/ActiveNode.html#eager-loading